# WebSerial getPorts() method return nothing

Tags: google-chrome, web, serial-port

I have tried [Web Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/).

If I use [requestPort() method](https://wicg.github.io/serial/#requestport-method), like this :

```
<button id="connect">Connect</button>

<script>
    const connectButton = document.getElementById("connect");
    connectButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
            console.log(port)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    });
</script>
```

It's OK, to prompt the user for which device the site should be allowed to control.

But with [getPorts() method](https://wicg.github.io/serial/#getports-method), like this :

```
<script>
    const connectButton = document.getElementById("connect");
    connectButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const ports = await navigator.serial.getPorts();
            console.log(ports)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    });
</script>
```

I got nothing with `ports.length == 0`

Could anybody help this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A user must approve access to the device before it can be accessed. You initiate the request via:

```js
navigator.serial.requestPort()
```

To get a list of ports that **have already been selected/approved** by the user from the permission popup you call:

```js
navigator.serial.getPorts()
```

You can check out the https://webserial.io source for an example here:

https://github.com/williamkapke/webserial/blob/main/src/stores/connection.js#L41